# sum of squares or square of total?

Tags: newrelic-platform

According to https://newrelic.com/docs/plugin-dev/metric-data-for-the-plugin-api plugins should also report the sum of squares for the specified period. Taking a look at the JSON example, I'd say this is more a square of the total value. E.g.:

```
{
  "name": "Primary MySQL Database",
  "guid": "com.your_company_name.plugin_name",
  "duration" : 60,
  "metrics" : {
    "Component/ProductionDatabase[Queries/Second]": 100,
    "Component/AnalyticsDatabase[Queries/Second]": {
      "min" : 2,
      "max" : 10,
      "total": 12,
      "count" : 2,
      "sum_of_squares" : 144
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously there were two values, 2 and 10. According to the sample the `sum_of_squares` is `(10+2)^2=144` which I would define as "square of total".
For me however, the term "sum of squares" would be `2^2+10^2=104`.

So when taking about multi-value metrics - which one is the correct number?

Comment: I'm no expert on multi valued metrics, but I'm pretty sure you're right about what the definition of a sum of squares is. What they're calling a sum of squares seems more like a square of the sum.

Comment: I see New Relic has updated their example to set the sum_of_squares to 104.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely right that the example values as documented are incorrect. I'll notify the relevant parties to update the documentation.

In the common case where only a single metric value is being reported, the count will be (1), in which case squaring the "total" value yields the correct result.